# Gsd-color disable

Tags: command-line, gnome, brightness, xrandr, colors

Is it possible to disable the `gsd-color`process please ?
this process keeps resetting my brightness with xrandr and i want to disable it on startup
tried this :

1. -- How-to -- The GNOME Settings Daemon's color plugin auto-start on/off switch is hidden by default. To make it visible:
2. Open Terminal and type: sudo sed -i
   "s/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g" /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop
   ~/.config/autostart/*.desktop To disable GNOME Settings Daemon's color plugin from auto-starting:
3. Open Command via ALT+F2
4. Type gnome-session-properties
5. Scroll down to GNOME Settings Daemon's color plugin and disable
   the checkbox and close the startup pref. window.
6. Now log-off to the login screen and log back in. Open Brightness
   Controller and set your colors / brightness. Open Chromium (or any
   other app that caused problem) and it should now keep your settings
   and never reset them.

found here : https://github.com/LordAmit/Brightness/issues/102

but sadly it doesn't work !

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: I tested my answer on Ubuntu 22.04. This question is from 2021 and I don't know if my answer can be applied to Ubuntu at that time.

On Ubuntu 22.04, `gsd-color` is started by the systemd service called `org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.service`.

You need to prevent systemd from starting the service. To do so, run `systemctl mask` like this:

```
systemctl --user mask --now org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.service

# If the service is successfully masked, this should print "masked".
systemctl --user is-enabled org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.service
```

To undo the masked service, run `systemctl unmask` as follows and then login again:

```
systemctl --user unmask org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.service

# If the service is successfully unmasked, this should print "static".
systemctl --user is-enabled org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.service
```